# Cyrillic font not displaying properly in Android

Tags: fonts

I have installed Evernote on a Lenovo P770 (running Android). The problem is, some Cyrillic text is displayed with strange hardly readable font. At the same time Cyrillic text with another font is displayed correctly. Other applications are having the same problem, so this is not specific to Evernote.

Screenshot below:

[image]

The device is not rooted.

Is it possible to replace this font with another in Android? Can I do it without rooting the phone?

Comment: All Cyrillic text in that screenshot looks fine to me. Can you clarify exactly what text you're referring to? Edit: do you mean the extra spacing between letters in some of the menu items?

Comment: Yes I mean the extra spacing. Note headers, menu items and some labels are displayed with this font. If some note has long header it is hardly readable. I think it is a pecularity of this font so I want to replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was **partially** solved.

1. Download .apk file from the device (with AirDroid for example)
2. Remove assets/fonts directory from the archive
3. Install the application with modified .apk file

I suspect that this bug appears again with every application update, so this fix has to be repeated after every update